# Do we need to Update table statistics after truncate?

Tags: postgresql

Do we need to Update table statistics after calling `truncate table` or it gets updated automatically?

[doc about truncate](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-truncate.html) says that:

> it reclaims disk space immediately, rather than requiring a subsequent VACUUM operation.

Ok, reclaims disk space, but it also updates statistics? do we need `ANALYZE table` after `TRUNCATE` anyway?

I found exactly same question but it's for `sql server`,   not for `postgres`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pratice no because TRUNCATE statement updates pg_class directly:

```
postgres=# select count(*) from t;
 count 
-------
     0
(1 row)

postgres=# insert into t select generate_series(1,1000000);
INSERT 0 1000000
postgres=# analyze t;
ANALYZE
postgres=# select relpages, reltuples from pg_class where relname='t';
 relpages | reltuples 
----------+-----------
     4425 |     1e+06
(1 row)

postgres=# truncate table t;
TRUNCATE TABLE
postgres=# select relpages, reltuples from pg_class where relname='t';
 relpages | reltuples 
----------+-----------
        0 |         0
(1 row)

postgres=#
```

It looks like TRUNCATE statement does not update pg_statistic table (this is table used by pg_stats view)but I notice that if the table is empty ANALYZE does not update pg_statistic table.

Comment: Thank you very much. " I notice that if the table is empty ANALYZE does not update pg_statistic table". hmm, interesting

Answer (score 1):

`TRUNCATE` removes some table statistics (the ones that are stored in `pg_class`), but it does not modify `pg_statistic`:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM waltest WHERE id < 100;
                         QUERY PLAN                          
-------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on waltest  (cost=0.00..170.01 rows=10001 width=4)
   Filter: (id < 100)
(2 rows)

TRUNCATE waltest;

EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM waltest WHERE id < 100;
                        QUERY PLAN                         
-----------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on waltest  (cost=0.00..41.88 rows=2550 width=4)
   Filter: (id < 100)
(2 rows)

SELECT * FROM pg_stats WHERE tablename = 'waltest' \gx
-[ RECORD 1 ]----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
schemaname             | laurenz
tablename              | waltest
attname                | id
inherited              | f
null_frac              | 0
avg_width              | 4
n_distinct             | -1
most_common_vals       | 
most_common_freqs      | 
histogram_bounds       | {1,100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000,1100,1200,1300,1400,1500,1600,1700,1800,1900,2000,2100,2200,2300,2400,2500,2600,2700,2800,2900,3000,3100,3200,3300,3400,3500,3600,3700,3800,3900,4000,4100,4200,4300,4400,4500,4600,4700,4800,4900,5000,5100,5200,5300,5400,5500,5600,5700,5800,5900,6000,6100,6200,6300,6400,6500,6600,6700,6800,6900,7000,7100,7200,7300,7400,7500,7600,7700,7800,7900,8000,8100,8200,8300,8400,8500,8600,8700,8800,8900,9000,9100,9200,9300,9400,9500,9600,9700,9800,9900,10000}
correlation            | 1
most_common_elems      | 
most_common_elem_freqs | 
elem_count_histogram   |
```

Note that empty tables are not estimated empty:

```
    /*
     * HACK: if the relation has never yet been vacuumed, use a minimum size
     * estimate of 10 pages.  The idea here is to avoid assuming a
     * newly-created table is really small, even if it currently is, because
     * that may not be true once some data gets loaded into it.  Once a vacuum
     * or analyze cycle has been done on it, it's more reasonable to believe
     * the size is somewhat stable.
```